# need help for creating submit screen new to swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a login screen - after login, I am displaying list in a table view with check boxes. After submitting button. all the selected check box labels should send to server.  Login screen and displaying table working how to write action for submit import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    private let dwarves = [
        "Sleepy", "Sneezy", "Bashful", "Happy",
        "Doc", "Grumpy", "Dopey",
        "Thorin", "Dorin", "Nori", "Ori",
        "Balin", "Dwalin", "Fili", "Kili",
        "Oin", "Gloin", "Bifur", "Bofur",
        "Bombur"]

    let simpleTableIdentifier = "SimpleTableIdentifier"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dwarves.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        simpleTableIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
        if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(
        style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier)
        }
        let image = UIImage(named: "unchecked")
        cell!.imageView.image = image
        let highlightedImage = UIImage(named: "checked")
        cell!.imageView.highlightedImage = highlightedImage


        cell!.textLabel.text = dwarves[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
    }
    /*func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let rowValue = dwarves[indexPath.row]
        for element in rowValue {

            sel = [rowValue]
            println(element)

            }


    }*/

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    let rowValue = dwarves[indexPath.row];        println("You selected cell \(indexPath.row)")



    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. You should read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first. And do not only ask "How to write" - show us first what you have already tried. You could store on didSelectTowatIndexPath your rowValues to an Array, and on a click you could send the data to the server.

Comment: how to store that selected in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `NSMutableArray` instance variable to hold the selected values:

```
var selected = NSMutableArray()
```

Then, in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, add to the array if the object does not exist or remove the object if it does exist.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let rowValue = dwarves[indexPath.row];        println("You selected cell \(indexPath.row)")
    // if the item exsits then remove it
    if selected.containsObject(rowValue) {
        selected.removeObject(rowValue)
    } else { // else the item doesn't exist so add it
        selected.addObject(rowValue)
    }
    println(selected)
}
```

Comment: thanks Fessler . working but when   I deselect it is not  removing from the list.   i need to store only selected rows and label.